# C++ "select" algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, lambda

Among the functionalities found in `std::algorithm` I can't seem to find one of the most basic I can think of: selected a subset of a collection (for example, return all the odd numbers, all the employees that have status == 'employed', all items that cost less that 20 dollars).

So, given a list of ints like

```
vector<int> ints {1, 9, 3, 27, 5, 19, 3, 8, 2, 12};

vector<int> evens = ?
vector<int> greaterThan7 = ?
```

How to find those that are even and those that are greater than 7?

Comment: [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) doesn't work for you?

Comment: By the way... there is no such thing as `std::algorithm`. You probably meant to write `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For example

```
vector<int> ints {1, 9, 3, 27, 5, 19, 3, 8, 2, 12};
vector<int> evens;

std::copy_if( ints.begin(), ints.end(), std::back_inserter( evens ),
              []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; } );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ints { 1, 9, 3, 27, 5, 19, 3, 8, 2, 12 };
    std::vector<int> evens;

    std::copy_if( ints.begin(), ints.end(), std::back_inserter( evens ),
                  []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; } );

    for ( int x : evens ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Its output is

```
8 2 12
```

Comment: Remember that those functions are not lazy, compared to the Select in C# or other languages so have a potential of being very expensive.

Comment: The question's sample code isn't lazy either, to be fair. You could wrap `std::find_if` in an iterator adaptor if you need a lazily-evaluated filter.

Comment: @MatsFredriksson we'll have ranges soon for lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 19):

If you want something more functional, you can check out the boost range library. Specifically, [`filtered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html):

```
for (int i : ints | filtered([](int i){return i > 7;}))
{
    ...
}
```

This gives you a lazy view, without constructing a new container.

---

You can get the same from Eric Niebler's [`range-v3`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views):

```
for (int i : view::filter(ints, [](int i){return i > 7;})
{
    ...
}
```

with the benefit that you can just assign that to a vector too (so you can choose if it's lazy or eager, which Boost.Ranges does not allow).

```
std::vector<int> greaterThan7 = view::filter(ints, [](int i){return i > 7;});
std::vector<int> sameThing    = ints | view::filter([](int i){return i > 7;});
```

Comment: OK.  I thought you meant `sameThing` to be initialized with the boost version.

Comment: @NathanOliver No. boost doesn't support that. I meant to demonstrate that ranges supports piping too.

Comment: OK.  I didn't know that. I always learn something from your answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Barry I had the same misunderstanding as Nathan first, maybe you could write this into your answer

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your exact requirements are, consider [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) (or `std::partition`). It reorders elements in the range such that all which satisfy a predicate come first. You can think of it as splitting the range into a "subset" and a "not subset" part. Here is an example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    using std::cbegin;
    using std::cend;

    std::vector<int> ints { 1, 9, 3, 27, 5, 19, 3, 8, 2, 12 };

    auto const greater_than_7 = [](int number) { return number > 7; };

    auto const iter_first_not_greater_than_7 = std::stable_partition(begin(ints), end(ints), greater_than_7);

    for (auto const_iter = cbegin(ints); const_iter != iter_first_not_greater_than_7; ++const_iter)
    {
        std::cout << *const_iter << "\n";
    }
}
```

If, however, you are fine with copying each matching element to a new collection, for example because the source range must not be modified, then use `std::copy_if`.

---

Perhaps what you are really looking for is a **view** of an unmodifiable range. In this case, you are approaching the problem from the wrong direction. You don't need a particular algorithm; a more natural solution to the problem would be a filtering **iterator**, like for example [Boost's Filter Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html). You can use the one in Boost or study its implementation to learn how you could write filtering iterators yourself.

Comment: This was what I was going to suggest. `std::stable_partition`, specifically.